# is this a subset of real vector space given

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Decide which of the following are subspaces of the given real vector spaces. Justify your answers by using the subspace theorem or by giving a specific counterexample to show it is not a subspace.

$$ B = \{(a, b, c) \in R^3:b \geq0\} \subseteq R^3$$

$$ C = \{(a - b, a+ b, 7a): a, b \in R\} \subseteq R^3$$

**Solution B:**

Let $\alpha = -1$ be a scalar multiple in $\mathbb{R}$ and u = (1,2,3) $\epsilon$ B.
Then, $\alpha u = ( \ (-1*1), (-1*2), (-1*3)\ ) = (-1, -2, -3)$

Since $-2 < 0$,  $a_2 {>} 0$ is not satisfied. Hence, B is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

**Solution C:**
let $u=(u_1-u_2, u_1+u_2, 7u_1)$ and $v=(v_1-v_2, v_1+v_2, 7v_1)$ $\epsilon$ C

then $u+v = ( (u_1+v_1)-(u_2+v_2),\ \  (u_1+v_1)+(u_2+v_2),\ \ (7(u_1+v_1) )$

hence, addition vector addition is closed

let $\alpha$ be a scalar multiple

then $\alpha C = (\alpha(a-b), \alpha(a+b), \alpha(7a))\ \ \epsilon \ \ \mathbb{R^3}$

conclusion, both addition and scalar multiple is closed thus it is a subspace.

Can someone please check if my approach is correct?

Comment: For the first, you mean $a_2\geq 0$ is not satisfied, not $a_2>0$.  Otherwise, these both look correct.  As an aside, for C you could combine both steps into one, checking that $\alpha u + \beta v$ is in your set effectively checking both conditions at once.

Comment: Thank you for checking it for me. I will make the required change and make it more efficient as per your comment

Comment: You said $\alpha C\in\Bbb R^3$ but you want $\alpha C\in C$